# Merge column data into row in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dataframes :

1st dataframe

```
cat         2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005
1            779     771     754     740     760     747
2          1311.2   1285.2  1271.2  1276.5  1270.6  1281
3           836      814    810      800     802     799
4           914      892    888      878     880     877
5           992      970    966      956     958     955
```

2nd dataframe

```
year  data
2000  1
2001  4
2002  7
2003  10
2004  6
2005  3
```

i would like to merge above these two dataframe in following way?is it possible?

```
cat         2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005
1           779     771     754      740     760    747
2          1311.2  1285.2   1271.2   1276.5 1270.6  1281
3           836      814    810      800     802    799
4           914      892    888      878     880    877
5           992      970    966      956     958    955
6(merge entry)1         4    7        10      6      3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to transpose `df2` and then you can append it to `df1`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2.T])
```

Result:

```
        2000    2001    2002    2003    2004  2005
1      779.0   771.0   754.0   740.0   760.0   747
2     1311.2  1285.2  1271.2  1276.5  1270.6  1281
3      836.0   814.0   810.0   800.0   802.0   799
4      914.0   892.0   888.0   878.0   880.0   877
5      992.0   970.0   966.0   956.0   958.0   955
data     1.0     4.0     7.0    10.0     6.0     3
```

Comment: You are welcome. Use `ignore_index=True` if you want to reset indices.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard at all. You have to transpose the second dataframe and add its values in the rows of the first dataframe. Use the .T command.